# How to update the text values based on button click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shopping-cart, modifier

I have shopping cart app in swiftUI . Currently when I click the add to cart button that time , it is able to add the product record into view . But here is the problem . W**hen I click the button twice that time same product record get again , to be more straight forward having duplicate record and seconds problem is , I am expecting to update the quantities of the product as well but I'm not sure how to do it** Please suggest me to do it batter way.

Here is my code for List view ..

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ProductListView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                    if viewModel.productLists.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {
 List(viewModel.productList, id: \.self) { product in
                    ProductListViewCell(productData: product)

                        } .listStyle(.grouped)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Product List"))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for cell..

```
struct ProductListViewCell: View {

    let productData: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let url = URL(string: productData.thumbnail) {
                ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5) {
                Text("Name: " +  (productData.title))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text("Description: " + (productData.description))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

                Text("Price: £" + String(productData.price))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.subheadline)

                Button {
                    order.add(item: productData)

                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "cart.badge.plus")

                        Text("Add to Cart")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 150 , height: 40)

                }
                .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my order class ..

```
import SwiftUI

class Order: ObservableObject {

    @Published var product = [Product]()

    func add(item: Product) {
        product.append(item)
    }
    func remove(item: Product) {
        if let index = product.firstIndex(of: item) {
            product.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for order view..

```
struct OrderView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    var body: some View {
           NavigationStack {
               List {
                   Section {
                       ForEach(order.product) { item in
                           HStack(spacing: 20) {
                               if let url = URL(string: item.thumbnail) {
                                   ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                                       .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                        .padding(.bottom, -10)
                                       .clipShape(Circle())
                               }
                               VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                   Text("Name: \(item.title)")
                                   Text("Price :£\(item.price)")
                                   Button("Show details") {

                                   }.foregroundColor(.gray)
                               }
                               HStack {
                                   Image(systemName: "multiply")
                                   Text("1")
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   Section {
                       NavigationLink("Place Order") {
                       }
                   }
               }
               .navigationTitle("Order")
           }
       }
   }
```

Here is the screenshot for product list view ..

[image]

**Here is the screenshot having duplicate record when I click the add to button three time but I want only single record with Quantity 3.**

[image]

Comment: This needs a [mre]. No one can run this code as included here

Comment: Ok . which part of the you want to me add here please ?

Comment: You haven't shown your `Order` structure/class - That is where you need to do the work.  When you call `order.add()` that function needs to determine if the item already exists in the order and either increment the quantity or add a new item with quantity 1

Comment: I have updated the code with class and product list view

Comment: Please read the page that describes what a [mre] is -- it'll make it clear what to include and what not to so that there's _enough_ info here to run the code but not irrelevant code that obscures the issue.

Comment: I have remove the code form Product List view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `Product` class you should have a `quantity` variable.
- In `Order.add(item:)` you should check if `Product` exists in `products` array, and increase its `quantity`, as the following:

```swift
class Order: ObservableObject {

    @Published var products = [Product]()

    func add(item: Product) {
        var exists = false
        products.forEach { product in
            if product.id == item.id {
                exists = true
                product.quantity += 1
            }
        }
        
        if !exists {
            product.append(item)
        }
    }

    //The rest of your code...
}
```

- Finally, you need to display the `quantity` in `OrderView`, as the following:

```swift
...
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "multiply")
        Text(item.quantity)
    }
...
```

> Fixed your typo in `Order` class: `product:[Product]` -> `products:[Product]`