# SwiftUI tab view with Shopping cart

Tags: ios, swiftui, shopping-cart, swiftui-tabview

I have the view in swiftUI. I have the list of tab view . Here what I'm trying to do . when I click the add to cart button, I am expecting the cart value to increase and it working fine but the problem is the count is displaying at bottom of the tab view, I want it at top of the cart view  like in preview , it show correctly.

Here is the Main view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

   @EnvironmentObject var  order: Order

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            OrderView()
                .tabItem {
                    CartButton(numberOfProducts: order.product.count)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Cart button View ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct CartButton: View {
    var numberOfProducts: Int

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Image(systemName: "cart")
                .padding(.top, 5)

            if numberOfProducts > 0 {
                Text("\(numberOfProducts)")
                    .font(.caption2).bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    .background(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.835))
                    .cornerRadius(50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the preview of the cart button and showing correctly..

[image: preview]

Here is the screenshot of the tabview.As it showing when I click the add to cart button it increases the count and showing at Botton of the cart image ..
[image: tabview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get very little control over what is displayed in a tab item. You cannot do fancy things with `ZStack`s. From my experience, SwiftUI just finds some image and some text from the view you provide, and displays them in a system-defined way.

That said, you are reinventing [badges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/badge(_:)-8adyq). This sort of "red circle with text in it" on a tab bar can be created by modifying the tab's view (not the view in `tabItem`) with `badge(_:)`.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        OrderView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "cart")
            }
            // this also automatically hides the badge when 0
            .badge(order.product.count)
    }
}
```

Badges only show up in list rows, menus and tab bars, so if you want to have a such a button at another place, you can still use your `CartButton` view.

Comment: Thanks you very much . Can you please help of this question..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77392356/how-to-update-the-text-values-based-on-button-click-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment136437090_77392356