# Using TextFiled in Swift UI update two record same time

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, textfield, shopping-cart

I using Textfiled where I can enter quantity of the product. I'm using $Binding  property wrapper . This is a shopping cart view(Order view) . **The problem is when I enter the values it update the both shopping cart quantity as well . When I edit the quantity on TextField then next record should not update .I'm also having spacing issue between TextField and Quantity text ..**

Problem is on this line code ..

```
 HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                Text("Name: \(item.title)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .bold()
                                Text("Quantity:")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .bold()
                                TextField("amount", text: $quantity)
                                    .border(.green)
                                    .frame(maxHeight: 10, alignment: .leading)
                            }
```

Here is cell for product view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListViewCell: View {

        let productData: Product
        @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                if let url = URL(string: productData.thumbnail) {
                    ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5) {
                    Text("Name: " +  (productData.title))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .font(.headline)
    
                    Text("Description: " + (productData.description))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    
                    Text("Price: £" + String(productData.price))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .font(.subheadline)
    
                    Button {
                        order.add(item: productData)
    
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "cart.badge.plus")
    
                            Text("Add to Cart")
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 150 , height: 40)
    
                    }
                    .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for Product list ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
                    if viewModel.productLists.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {

                        List(viewModel.productList, id: \.self) { product in
                            ProductListViewCell(productData: product)

                        } .listStyle(.grouped)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Here is my order view code ..

```
      struct OrderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    @State private var quantity: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(order.product) { item in
                        Section {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Description")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Action")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                        }

                        HStack {
                            if let url = URL(string: item.thumbnail) {
                                ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                    .padding(.bottom, -10)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                            Spacer()

                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Stepper {
                                        Text("\(Image(systemName: "multiply"))\(quantity)")

                                    }
                                onIncrement: {
                                    quantity+=1

                                }
                                onDecrement: {
                                    if quantity > 1 {
                                        quantity -= 1
                                    }
                                }

                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.835))
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            order.remove(item: item)
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }

                        VStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                Text("Name: \(item.title)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .bold()

                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("Price: £\(item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                Text("Sub Total: £\(quantity * item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink("Place Order") {
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Order")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have repeated data (the products) in your order, but only a single `$quantity`, which is not linked to the product in any way.

I would also suggest that a `TextField` isn't the best UI element to use; You need to take care of validating/parsing the content to ensure it is a number.

There is a simpler control available - A [`Stepper`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stepper) - If you use a `Stepper` you can eliminate the +/- buttons you have added and you don't need to worry about invalid values being entered.

Something like -

```
struct OrderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(order.product) { item in
                        Section {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Description")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Action")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                        }

                        HStack {
                            if let url = URL(string: item.thumbnail) {
                                ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                    .padding(.bottom, -10)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                            Spacer()

                                
                                HStack {
                                    Stepper {
                                        Text("\(item.quantity)")
                                    }
                                    onIncrement: {
                                        item.quantity+=1
                                    }
                                    onDecrement: {
                                        if item.quantity > 1 {
                                           item.quantity -= 1
                                    }
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.835))
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            order.remove(item: item)
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
           

                        VStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                Text("Name: \(item.title)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("Price: £\(item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                Text("Total: £\(item.quantity * item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink("Place Order") {
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Order")
        }
    }
}
```

From a design perspective, there is no need for a text description like "Move to Trash" when the icon is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with Stepper when I try to update the quality of the item the rest of the record also update . I want only particular row will be updated.

Comment: Basically when I increase or decrease the Item with Stepper . it also increase or decrease rest of the items quantity into order view

Comment: As you can see form the Screen when you click the stepper + or - the rest of the cart record updated automatically

Comment: Because you still have a single quantity - `@State private var quantity: Int = 1` - Note that in my answer, the `quantity` is `item.quantity` - You need to update the quantity associated with each product in the order.

Comment: You need to take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77395223/3418066) to your previous question on board.